# Read remote file using python subprocess and ssh?

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess

How can I read  data from a big remote file using subprocess and ssh?

Comment: Do you want to run programs on the remote server with SSH that need to access the file? Do you want to copy the file to your computer with SCP? Do you want Python to be able to read or write directly to the file? You need to give more details about what you're trying to do for anyone to be able to answer this question.

Comment: In my program I would like to list the files under a specific directory on a remote server. The user then selects to operate on one of these files. The files are quite big so I want to be able to read on the fly (to avoid memory issues) ie line by line. If the line meets a condition; do something with the line until end of file is reached.

Answer (score 11):

```
import subprocess
ssh = subprocess.Popen(['ssh', 'user@host', 'cat', 'path/to/file'],
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in ssh.stdout:
    line  # do stuff
```

Comment: Ross, I have the exact same command that you suggest but that only reads the first line and does not read the other lines.. How do I make it read all the lines in the file?

Comment: I should say that by using the above you have, the file contents are read character by character.. how can i read a whole line completely? "split('\n')" does not seem to work..

Comment: Remove `.readline()` after `ssh.stdout`, you want to loop on the output not the first line from it.

Comment: @JordanTrudgett Hmm, I submitted the edit when I said, but I can't find anything about it being rejected.  Submitted it again.

Comment: @RossPatterson  will this affect the servers bandwidth?

Comment: @haifzhan No more or less than any other way to transfer the file.

Comment: I am not getting any feedback - dont know if it can connect but not find the file or..

Answer (score 1):

The answer above will work, but you'll have to setup your ssh login to use no password between [your boxes](http://linuxproblem.org/art_9.html). There are other ways to transfer files between computers using Python. A simple way, without authentication is to setup an apache server and use an [http request](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html).

Answer (score 0):

For performance improvement, which is important when the file is big, there is rsync. For more information about the exact improvement see following post and the answer from Rafa:
[How does `scp` differ from `rsync`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244585/how-does-scp-differ-from-rsync)

The algorithm would then be the following using rsync

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(["rsync", host-ip+'/path/to/file'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in ssh.stdout:
    line  # do stuff
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `iter` with `readline` to read each full line:

```
for i in iter(f.stdout.readline,"")
```