# Having issues reading a remote file while using subprocess

Tags: python, file, subprocess, cat

I do the following and not able to read the file "word_file.txt" line by line..

```
 f = subprocess.Popen(["../../../script.sh", "cat", "word_file.txt"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            out = f.stdout.readline()
            print "......."
            for i in f.stdout.readline():
                print "I>>>>>>>>>>>", i
```

the i that gets printed, prints every single character separately.

So, I tried doing..

```
for i in f.stdout.readline().split('\n'):
            print "I>>>>>>>>>>>", i
```

[Read remote file using python subprocess and ssh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135744/read-remote-file-using-python-subprocess-and-ssh) - addresses the same issue but their solution isnt working for me.

But that does not seem the right this to do. I get no output..

Comment: try `iter(f.stdout.readline,"")`

Comment: iter(f.stdout.readline(),"")
           TypeError: iter(v, w): v must be callable -> I get the 2 lines of error..

Comment: no parens on `readline`,

Comment: I get no output, Padraic! after removing the parens

Comment: I am not fully understanding your problem, are you getting output from either of the attempts in your question? You are also using `for i in iter(f.stdout.readline,"")`?

Comment: Dammit.. I just used it with the for loop and it works fine. Thanks!

Comment: Why can I not get the green check mark next to your responses. I just get the arrow option.

Comment: Because I did not add an answer, these are just comments, I will add an answer to close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `iter` with `readline` to read each full line:

```
for i in iter(f.stdout.readline,"")
```